# Flutter JSON not reading correctly

Tags: android, ios, json, dart, flutter

this might take a while...
I've been trying to get my Dart/Flutter code to return data from [BlockChainTicker](https://blockchain.info/ticker) (**Specifically I would like to see everything from the AUD line**) and leave this in the Debug Console. When I do so, I get this error back from the Console

```
E/flutter ( 8656): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 8656): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' where
E/flutter ( 8656):   _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
E/flutter ( 8656):   String is from dart:core
E/flutter ( 8656):   List is from dart:core
```

My code might seem amature but I only have about a weeks experience in this language, so thanks for any patience you might take in reading over this.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;



class First extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<First> {

  List data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull("http://blockchain.info/ticker"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    );
    data = JSON.decode(response.body);
    print(data[1]["AUD"]);

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text("Get data"),
          onPressed: getData,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top level of your json is a map (not a list - in json, lists are enclosed in brackets)

```
{
  "USD" : {"15m" : 7492.85, "last" : 7492.85, "buy" : 7492.85, "sell" : 7492.85, "symbol" : "$"},
  "AUD" : {"15m" : 9899.28, "last" : 9899.28, "buy" : 9899.28, "sell" : 9899.28, "symbol" : "$"},
  "BRL" : {"15m" : 28214.31, "last" : 28214.31, "buy" : 28214.31, "sell" : 28214.31, "symbol" : "R$"},
```

So change:

```
print(data[1]["AUD"]);
```

to

```
print(data["AUD"]); // prints the whole AUD map
print(data['AUD']['last']); // prints the AUD 'last' double

String isoCode = 'AUD';
print('$isoCode -> ${data[isoCode]}');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, been scouring the web for a fix so I’m glad I got a response. :)

Comment: Also Richard, when I use this code I don’t get the AUD displayed on the string in the Debug Console, can you guide me as to what code I would rather use?

Comment: Strange, it works for me in a little test harness. Can you clarify what you expect to see? Don't see?

Comment: This is what I see in the Console : **{15m: 10112.61, last: 10112.61, buy: 10112.61, sell: 10112.61, symbol: $}** and this is what I want to see **"AUD" : {15m: 10112.61, last: 10112.61, buy: 10112.61, sell: 10112.61, symbol: $}** (Really I just want to see that AUD has been selected without referring to the table to see if I've picked the right line).

Comment: like that, perhaps?

Comment: Perfect, thanks for both your help. I now see **AUD -> {15m: 10081.321613981092, last: 10081.321613981092, buy: 10081.321613981092, sell: 10081.321613981092, symbol: $}** in my console, exactly what I needed! :)