# query of json in flutter

Tags: android, arrays, json, flutter

I've got the following json response from spotify api:

```
{
   "artists" : {
     "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=U2&type=artist&offset=0&limit=20",
   "items" : [ {
       "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/51Blml2LZPmy7TTiAg47vQ"
     },
      "followers" : {
        "href" : null,
        "total" : 3146466
    },
     "genres" : [ "irish rock", "permanent wave", "rock" ],
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/51Blml2LZPmy7TTiAg47vQ",
      "id" : "51Blml2LZPmy7TTiAg47vQ",
     "images" : [ {
       "height" : 640,
         "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/e22d5c0c8139b8439440a69854ed66efae91112d",
       "width" : 640
      }, {
       "height" : 160,
       "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/7293d6752ae8a64e34adee5086858e408185b534",
        "width" : 160
      } ],
     "name" : "U2",
      "popularity" : 76,
      "type" : "artist",
     "uri" : "
```

I would like to get the id value, which in this case is

> 51Blml2LZPmy7TTiAg47vQ

but I can't figure out how to make a query in this json using dart.

I tried out as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651451/flutter-json-not-reading-correctly) but did not work.

Is there any way to make a query on json with flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `json.decode(string)['artists']['items'][0]['id']`

`json.decode` decodes the string to a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` containing nested `Map`s and `List`s into which you can index. (Maps are indexed by key; Lists are indexed by integer.)